# Codesandbox preview isn't working without an indication of any problem. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

Right now I'm trying to copy random pages from the internet to improve my skills. Right know I'm in process of copying https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/is_not_null.phphttps://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/is_not_null.php this page.

Everything looks great in VS code and when I'm opening my html file with chrome, but when I'm uploading it to the Codesandbox, it simply doesn't show anything in the preview window! There are no indications of any problems, so I'm completely frustrated. UPD: now it does, but I cant figure out what's the case.

I apologize in advance if I posted question in the wrong topic, I will definitely learn to do it right.

I've tried to delete the default .js and .css files. Also I've tried to repeat all steps from the incognito mode - nothing helps.

Here is the Codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-meitner-57mlq?fontsize=14
The files are in the "site" folder.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I think the problem is that there's nothing in your public folder.
And the index.html is completely empty.

Comment: Yeah, that helped! Thank you so much!

Comment: Wait, I'll write that in an answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's nothing inside your public folder.

Additionally your `index.html` is empty.